# React native: Send data from when phone to another without internet

Tags: react-native

I am trying to send data from one phone to another using a react native app. Is there any solutions or modules there?

Comment: do you mean blootuth?

Comment: Yeah, something like that ... I used [react-native-bluetooth-classic] (https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic) but it doesn't work perfectly; some devices can connect to some devices but some cannot. I've used Huawei and samsung devices for testing.

Comment: If I get a chance this weekend I'll try it out with a second device. I only have a huawei and LG 5. You should open an issue on github and I can track it better.  I vaguely remember reading somewhere that this is trouble and my not work fully while looking at resources myself.

Comment: Did you find a package that works

Comment: @ThanveerShah, I stopped working on that project for a long time now. I remember that I tried Bluetooth for a while, then I found a problem with connection between iOS and Android. Then, I have tried working with Wifi and hotspot, I think I couldn't make it work.
It's been a long time, I don't remember what I did with that project.
Sorry.

Comment: No worries, thank you

Comment: Did it work Android to Android?